# Place forest side by side with text/equations

Tags: forest

I would like to place the tree on the right side of the page and make the list come upwards so that they stand side by side. Have been trying several things but could not work it out. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}[2014/10/29]
\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor {processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

 
\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    circle, draw, 
    minimum size=1.5em,
    inner sep=2pt,
%
    s sep=3mm,
    l sep=7mm,
    edge={-Straight Barb} % arrows head defined in 'arrows.meta'
            }
[A
    [B
        [F]
    ]
    [C
        [D
            [G
                [F
                    [H]
                ]
                [H]
            ]
        ]
        [E
            [F]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}


\begin{aligned}
&[(A,0)]\\
&[ ]\\
&\\
&[(B,11), (C,26)]\\
&[(A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(C,26), (F,74)]\\
&[(B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(D,31), (E,38), (F,74)]\\
&[(C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(E,38), (G,46), (F,74)]\\
&[(D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(G,46), (F,74), (F,109)]\\
&[(E,38), (D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(F,53), (H,61), (F,74), (F,109)]\\
&[(G,46), (E,38), (D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(H,61), (H,73), (F,74), (F,109)]\\
&[(F,53), (G,46), (E,38), (D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]
\end{aligned}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the environment `multicols`?

Comment: No, how would that one work?

Comment: Do you need the slashbox.sty?  I can't run the file to help.

Comment: `$\begin{aligned} .... \end{aligned}$\begin{forest} .. \end{forest}`? (Make sure there are no empty lines between `$` and `\begin{forest}`.) Or did you have some different vertical alignment in mind?

Comment: @MiguelGarcia See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the classic way to do that if I have understood well the question.

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{forest}

 
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
$\begin{aligned}
&[(A,0)]\\
&[ ]\\
&\\
&[(B,11), (C,26)]\\
&[(A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(C,26), (F,74)]\\
&[(B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(D,31), (E,38), (F,74)]\\
&[(C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(E,38), (G,46), (F,74)]\\
&[(D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(G,46), (F,74), (F,109)]\\
&[(E,38), (D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(F,53), (H,61), (F,74), (F,109)]\\
&[(G,46), (E,38), (D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]\\
&\\
&[(H,61), (H,73), (F,74), (F,109)]\\
&[(F,53), (G,46), (E,38), (D,31), (C, 26), (B,11), (A,0)]
\end{aligned}$


\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    circle, draw, 
    minimum size=1.5em,
    inner sep=2pt,
%
    s sep=3mm,
    l sep=7mm,
    edge={-Straight Barb} % arrows head defined in 'arrows.meta'
            }
[A
    [B
        [F]
    ]
    [C
        [D
            [G
                [F
                    [H]
                ]
                [H]
            ]
        ]
        [E
            [F]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]